# Motion tracking

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I need to track single object's motion from frame to frame. I only need to know its position. But sometimes the object may go beyond the frame's boundaries partly (even most part) and sometimes it can approach the camera so closely that it will not fit in the frame. Which algorithm is the best for this purpose?

Comment: Whad did you try so far? What did you study so far?

Comment: That's why I ask. I didn't study anything so far except I've looked through opencv.

Comment: Sammy: If you're going to answer someone's question, please be constructive.  Someone curious about what is a good simple opencv motion tracking algorithm is a perfectly valid question.  I ran into this looking for the same thing actually, and your rude response helps nobody.

Answer (score 1):

The question seems not to be specific. What are you tracking?

Is it just a colored object (which is simplest), use threshold method for that color and use contour or method of moment to find its position. Then even if it goes out and come back, still it will be tracked.

http://aishack.in/tutorials/tracking-colored-objects-in-opencv/

Or whatever it is, try to isolate the blob first.

And if i misunderstood the question, please specify with few more details.